# Is this javascript vulnerable to dom based XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript, dom

I was testing `example.com` and i found a js reflection point. If i send the following request:

`https://example.com/?token=test%22test="'-confirm(1)-'`

I can see the following in server response:

```
<script nonce="">
window.meta    = {
"token": "Token\"xss=\"'-confirm(1)-'",
"dToken": "dt\"xss=\"'-confirm(1)-'",
"Id": "11"
</script>
```

Is this code vulnerable to Dom Based XSS? If yes, which payload could i try to trigger an alert box?

I already tried to close the `</script>` tag but < and > are filtered.

Comment: What does it do with a backslash? Also, your URL and server response don't seem to quite match. Any chance you have a mistake in your question?

Answer (score 3):

No it's not vulnerable to XSS based on the provided information. The interpolated URL query parameter `token` has quote marks escaped (`\"` instead of just `"`) so you cannot break out of the string. Because of this it is impossible to inject executable code, opposed to simply changing the content of a JavaScript string variable.

As you pointed out, it is also impossible to close/reopen the `script` tag.

As noted in the comments, if backslashes are not escaped (which we don't know), you can use an additional `\` to escape the first backslash of `\"` so that it becomes `\\"` in which case you can break out of the string because the `"` character is now no longer escaped.

Comment: If it doesn't escape backslashes then it is vulnerable despite escaping the double quote

Comment: @ConorMancone,

If i insert a single backslash it prints `\\\"xss=\"'-confirm(1)-'",`

Comment: @Pong if it is escaping backslashes and quotes then it sounds like it is not vulnerable. If they didn't escape the backslash then you could add a backslash before the one that escapes the double quote, turning it into a literal backslash and breaking out